# UITableViewCell image always showing the last cell image

Tags: swift, image, uitableview

I am struggling in displaying images in tableview cell. I do not post all the code, but this is what I did:

1. Parse json into an array and get the url of the img to downaload
2. Save the images into the document folder adding the file extension and unique name for each item

   ```
   let whereToSavePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
   ```
3. Display the content in a table view and load the image from the directory

Here is my code in the tableview  `cellForRowAt indexPath` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let findPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

    for i in 0...allCards.count - 1 {

        cell?.textLabel?.text = allCards[indexPath.row].name
        let savedFile = (findPath[0] + "/" + allCards[i].cardID + ".png")
        print(savedFile)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: savedFile)
        cell?.imageView?.image = image
     }
    return cell!
}
```

Every cell display correctly the card name but always the same image, the last one saved. I tried also with:

```
allCards[indexpath.row]
```

But in this case no image is display

If I print in the console the savedFile the files name are correct, for each card I have the right file saved and if I go in the document folder the pictures are there with right name

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at issue here is the loop inside of cell at index path. This function is called once for every row returned by the rows in section function. So you should almost never need a loop in this function.  Try something like the following.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let findPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let card = allCards[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = card.name
    let savedFile = (findPath[0] + "/" + card.cardID + ".png")
    print(savedFile)
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: savedFile)
    cell?.imageView?.image = image
    return cell!
}
```